# Google Play Game Services - Managing achievements

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

According to the GPGS website-

> Use the client libraries. The mobile client libraries employ a number
>      of strategies to reduce the calls you make to the service. For
>      instance, achievement and leaderboard data is cached, so a user can
>      view their achievements as often as they'd like without requiring the
>      service to make multiple calls. Both the Android and iOS client
>      libraries will know not to send a player's score to the server if
>      your score isn't as good as one you recently submitted. The Android
>      library also automatically combines frequent achievement increment
>      calls when it detects that you are being rate limited.

I'm specifically interested in 'viewing achievements without requiring the service to make multiple calls'. As far as I can see, the best way to do this would be to use the OnAchievementsLoadedListener and get a reference to the achievementBuffer.

Will that buffer be updated when an achievement state is changed and is it okay not to close that buffer immediately? If not, the OnAchievementsUpdatedListener does not pass a buffer or even and indiviudal achievement reference so how would I get the updated collection of achievements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#loadAchievements%28com.google.android.gms.games.achievement.OnAchievementsLoadedListener,%20boolean%29

Set forceReload argument to false to gain the advantages of data-caching :)